# Extract Google search URLs using R & Extract Texts from each URLS

Tags: r, url, text, mining

I need to extract Google search URLs & Extract Texts from those each URLs using R.

The goal is to classify each websites that appears from the Google search.

Please help if any one knows how.

Comment: You can rely on `RCurl` and `XML` packages to build such tool.

Comment: Generally, the expectation on SO is that you demonstrate that you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself before asking someone else to solve it for you. Show what you've tried, and be specific about how it did not work (e.g., show an example of expected/needed results).

Comment: look at the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908989/extract-text-from-search-result-urls-using-r/45910514?noredirect=1#comment78818195_45910514)